# Stop website text being editable

Tags: html, css

I have, what i would consider to be the strangest problem ive encountered for a long while.

I created the following page

http://www.business-helpline.com/4/

This is a static html page cobbled together and edited by me.

All of the text in the browser is editable. I can just click on the page and type what i want. As if it was in an input field. Im no novice when it comes to html and all appears to be ok to me. Can someone point me in the right direction.

I have tried a number of devices and they are all doing the same

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.

Answer (score 3):

You have this rule:

```
h1, h2, h3, p {
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
}
```

The culprit is `-webkit-user-modify`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify) (*which refers mainly to the -moz- version*):

> It was planned to determine whether or not the content of an element
>   can be edited by a user. This property is related to the
>   contenteditable attribute. A similar property user-focus was proposed
>   in early drafts of a predecessor of the CSS3 UI specification but was
>   rejected by the working group.

The `read-write` value means the user is able to read and write contents. Note that this is a non-standard feature and should not be used in a production website.

Comment: thank you very much. Not something i have seen before. I will mark as the accepted answer when it lets me